# How to use Solidify

Tags: solidify-modifier

I'm beginer for using blender. I would like to apply the function solidify to the following object but unfortunatly the surface is not very flat. Is someone can help me ? Kind Regards. Eric

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps expand this Q. to illustrate/explain your desired result.

Comment: I created a sphere shape that I cut in half (point by point...I imagine there's something simpler...?). I now want to fill the half sphere to obtain a perfectly flat solid shape (not hollow).

Comment: Thank you so much Aswin. I will try this evening ;-) Sincerely yours !

Comment: It seems to me all you want is to close the hole by adding a face? https://i.imgur.com/5IMHGvG.gif Or do you want to do it procedurally for some reason?

Answer (score 3):

if you're talking about filling in the hollow part of the sphere, you don't need solidify, coz what solidify does is, it adds thickness, it doesn't fill it up.
What you need to do is,

1. Go to edit mode by selecting the object and pressing Tab
2. Then go into the edge mode by pressing "2" above alphabets
3. Then select the outmost loop, by left-clicking on it while holding alt

[image]

4. Then press the "F" key and fill it in

Comment: L'animation est top ! MERCI ! Malheureusement les paramètres de mon blender ne doivent pas être bons. En effet, le mode opératoire fonctionne parfaitement mais l'angle de la boucle la plus extrême est arrondi et n'est pas saillant comme sur votre animation. Et de plus la surface se remplie en montant légèrement vers le centre alors que sur votre animation la surface est bien plate......;-(

Comment: J'ai trouvé ! ;-) J'utilisais au préalable la fonction subdivision mon objet ! Sans cette fonction le résultat est parfait mais mon objet n'est pas lissé ;-( Un grand merci !

Comment: Votre surface dés le départ est lisse. Comment faites vous cela Aswin ? MERCI

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Eric, but yes, all you have to do is, in object mode, select your object --> right click on it --> select "Shade Smooth".

Comment: If it's too much smooth you also need to enable "Auto-smooth" option. It can be found in your Properties panel (Right Bottom side panel) --> Object Data Properties (Green upside down triangle icon) --> Normals --> Autosmooth (Check/Tick the box)

Comment: Or you could add a Bevel Modifier first, use a low bevel amount, and maybe 3 segments. You can find these options in the Bevel modifier, after you add it. Then add a subdivision surface modifier to your object. It should look good

Comment: Bonjour Aswin. Ne soyez pas désolé c'est déjà super super sympa de m'aider !!!! ;-) J'ai applique le Shade Smooth. Effectivement visuellement sur blender c'est lisse comme sur votre animation ;-), mais quand j'exporte le fichier en stl et que je visualise l'objet dans slicerforfusion 360 il y a toujours les faces et les arrêtes.....Une idée ? Par ailleurs pouvez vous me dire comment mettre une image dans mon commentaire dans ce forum ? Ainsi je vous montrerais la forme obtenue dans slicerforfusion360. Très bonne journée. Eric

Comment: I thought you were trying to render something in Blender, Eric. So the thing with shade smooth - Autosmooth method is that, it's just for blender visualization purposes only.
Meaning, you can see it in blender, but when you export it out of blender, and load it into another software, like fusion360, you won't see it there.
For that, you'll have to use the 2nd method, the one with bevel modifier and subdivision surface modifier. After you apply those and then export out of blender, you should have what you were looking for in the first place.

Comment: Un grand merci Aswin. Je vais tester ce soir. Très bonne soirée.